nginx proxy php, how to set the access address as a subpath for php
I have a domain name, assuming it is "example.com". The backend nginx has already proxy a tomcat. The proxy domain name is "http://www.example.com/", which will jump to the tomcat service. This is normal at present.
Now I want to add another php service, on the same server, using the same nginx proxy, the url path is "http://www.example.com/php", and access the php code under /data/wwwroot/php .
However, when accessing "http://www.example.com/php", the tomcat service that will be forwarded will prompt "HTTP status 404 - Not Found", and the suffix shows that it is the "Apache Tomcat service".
So I suspect that the proxy is not effective. When I change the domain name of the php proxy to another one, such as php.example.com, the proxy is successful, but I don't want to encounter cross-domain problems. Please tell me how to set up php
This is the configuration of nginx proxy tomcat
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_set_header X-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 30s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}

This is the configuration of nginx proxy php. This is not normal.
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name www.example.com;


    location /php {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        alias  /data/wwwroot/php;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}

How should I solve this problem?

Your Tomcat and PHP configurations are in separate files / seperate server blocks with the hostname & port? That's not going to work. Indeed, if this is your configuration, nginx will be SHOUTING about this in the log files. Your log files are always the second place you should look when a server is not behaving correctly.
Move the PHP config out of the way then add the location block back into the tomcat config file after the existing location block.
